# Sorting datagridview issue

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Can someone help me to sort my datagridview(dataSource) . My field name is ControlCode and it's data type is varchar.

[Sorting Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZx98.png)

```
    Dim dataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dataSet As New DataTable
    Dim bindSource As New BindingSource

            cmd = "SELECT * FROM documentsinfo"

            com = New MySqlCommand(cmd, con)

            dataAdapter.SelectCommand = com
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet).ToString()
            bindSource.DataSource = dataSet
            dataSource.DataSource = bindSource
            dataAdapter.Update(dataSet)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your data type is nvarchar, its sorted as a string, not as an integer
You will need to order it like this

```
cmd = "SELECT * FROM documentsinfo ORDER BY CAST(ISNULL(NULLIF(ISNUMERIC(Idchecklist),0),2147483647) as INT)
```

**EDIT**

```
cmd = "SELECT * FROM documentsinfo ORDER BY ControlCode+0, ControlCode;
```

**EDIT 2**

With this code, it will ignore the first 6 characters (PRJCT-) and will order the column by the number, so as long as the column starts with the same characters (PRJCT-), it should work

```
cmd = "SELECT * FROM documentsinfo ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(`ControlCode`, 7) AS SIGNED)"
```

If it doesnt work Im out of ideas :/ and I suggest that you either remove the dash from your fields, so that my Edit 1 code works, or add an ID column to your database and sort by it.

Comment: Sir. Abichango error. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Comment: try replacing `ISNULL` with `IFNULL`

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTEGER)' at line 1.

Comment: I see the problem is with the dash, I didnt include it in my fiddle so it worked for me, but not for you, please check my last edit and give it a try.